# Duplicate record with Dragonfly gem image in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dragonfly-gem

How do I duplicate an ActiveRecord object with a dragonfly image?

I have the following.

model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  image_accessor :thumbnail

  attr_accessible :thumbnail, :remove_thumbnail, :retained_thumbnail

  validates :thumbnail, presence: true
end
```

controller:

```
def clone
  @event = Event.find(1).dup
  render :new
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :thumbnail %>
  <%= image_tag(@event.thumbnail.thumb('100x75').url) %>
  <label><%= f.check_box :remove_thumbnail %> Remove?</label>
  <%= f.file_field :thumbnail %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :retained_thumbnail %>
<% end %>
```

When I render the form, the image displays, but on submit, the image gets cleared out.

One thing, I'd like to make sure they are actually different images, so if I edit the original record, it will not affect the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I got it to work, overriding the object's `dup` behavior:

```
def dup
  target = Event.new(self.attributes.reject{|k,v| ["id", "attachment_uid"].include?(k) })
  target.attachment = self.attachment
  target
end
```

Then, when you call `save` on the target the image will be copied to the new location.

Note that on the first line I first tried `target = super`, to utilize the object's default `dup` behavior, but that caused the files of the original object to be deleted. The above solution finally did the trick for me.

Comment: Is the 'attachment' in this answer the same thing as your 'thumbnail' in your original question? It is inconsistent ;-)